# Add custom header with sql server database mail

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to add a custom header with database mail when sending mail with `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`

Comment: Can you add more detail to your question? What do you mean by custom header? What are you sending in the email?

Comment: when I send a mail from sql server database mail I will add a unique ID in header so if the mail send fails I can then track this with the ID ,and prepare a report which mails are not sent.

Comment: It's not possible to insert custom headers with sp_send_dbmail. You can query the db mail logs though, to create a report.

Comment: yes I know ,but log file not saved record about those mails which are field by SMTP. so I need a report SMTP label not SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't. Here is a [Connect Item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/573529/specify-mail-headers-in-sp-send-dbmail) which is marked as "won't fix" from 2011 requesting the same thing. Sounds like MS doesn't think it is a priority. This is the only official word from Microsoft I could find on the matter.

Comment: Good catch on the Connect item. +1 Sad that they won't add such a useful feature.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is a bit late, but I think I came up with a work around for this issue.  If you are using GMail as your email provider they allow any characters to come after a "+" in the email address and have that email go to a single mailbox.  For instance example+12344@gmail.com would go to example@gmail.com.  You can alter the reply-to email address to be example+[Your Message ID]@gmail.com when the message is sent.  If the message bounces you the reply-to email address in the header will then include the message ID and can be parsed out.  Hopefully this helps someone else searching for a solution to this problem.