# How to request Read Receipts for emails sent using SQLCLR Stored Procedure

Tags: .net, sql-server, email, sqlclr

I am tasked to get "read receipts" for the emails that are received by the client, and the emails are sent using a SQLCLR Stored Procedure. But I am not able to figure out how it's done. Could you please let me know how a Read receipt is configured for an email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had originally thought that using the built-in [Database Mail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189635.aspx) system and [sp_send_dbmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) would have been easier and more convenient for sending emails than using SQLCLR, but it seems that even if it would have been the better choice prior to asking this question, now that the desire is to request read receipts, using SQLCLR is probably the way to go since Database Mail doesn't support that header or passing in custom headers to add it in manually:

[Add custom header with sql server database mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821365/add-custom-header-with-sql-server-database-mail/29823772#29823772)

So, it looks like you will be adding an email header in .NET to your `MailMessage` object:

```cs
MailMessage email = new MailMessage();

email.Subject = "some exciting topic";
// set other properties of "email" object
email.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", "<addr_to_send_receipt_to@domain.tld>");
```

For more info, please see:

- [MailMessage.Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.headers.aspx) Property
- [How do I request a read receipt?](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/3.3.3.aspx)